Common clauses in two CNF formulas
How to identify the number of common clauses in two CNF formulas?
For example, for formulas:
(x1∨¬x2)∧(¬x1∨x3)∧(x2∨¬x3)
and
(x1∨¬x2)∧(x2∨¬x3)∧(x1∨x3),
the common clauses are (x1∨¬x2) and (x2∨¬x3).
If the question can be phrased better, I would appreciate a suggestion on that too.
Later edit:
I would prefer (a reference to) a solution using an SMT solver such as Z3, but really any solution would do. I'll just adjust it to the SMT-LIB format.
Something beyond a trivial syntactic equivalence check would be better.

maybe better suited for [cs.se]?

Indeed. Can I move the question there directly? Or do I have to delete it from here and reposted it there?

There are many different ways to achieve this; with varying performance characteristics. The classic answer is hash-consing, but it all depends on your representation. For instance, if x1/x2 etc. are represented as BDD variables, then clause equality would simply be pointer-equality.
SAT/SMT solvers usually use tricks to enable faster backtracking, which is the main operation in DPLL based techniques. See section 3 of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15414/s20/lectures/19-optimized-sat.pdf.

Thanks for your answer. I checked the slides you shared, and can't seem to figure out how I could use DPLL for my problem. DPLL searches for an interpretation of a given formula in order to witness its satisfiability.

You wouldn’t use DPLL for your problem. What I meant is DPLL and related algorithms do efficient clause analysis themselves, so you might be able to use the representation tricks they use.

If you want to use an SMT solver, simply give each conjunct a name and do a n*m loop to see if they’re equivalent. This’ll work but it won’t be performant if you have many/large clauses.

n*m equivalence checks would certainly work. Was wondering whether there are some known efficient algos an SMT solver could be instructed to do.

Constructing the BDD’s would be the fastest.
